# django - i18n - how is it possible?

Tags: django

I am stuck with this issue:

I have a page with `de` and `en` translations. in a `de`-page, there are videos in german.

usecase: John watches one of those videos in german and likes it. he says: "i want to share this video with my friend Charlie who is in US" and he sends this link to him:

```
http://blabla.com/de/das-video/12/
```

what I want is, if Charlie opens the link, he should be redirected to english version, to this link:

```
http://blabla.com/en/the-video/13/
```

my problem is:

once charlie opens the link, `request.LANGUAGE_CODE` in his side will become `de` because of i18n's [set_language](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/i18n.py#L18).

how can I redirect him to english version of this video`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django i18n is build in such a way, that if url contains a language prefix, then exactly that language will be shown.

But, if you'll remove the language prefix from url, then django will discover the user's preferred language first and then show corresponding version of a page.

So, in your case i think the best way would be to create a share button or maybe show the url for sharing on page. User must copy this url and not the url from browser address bar.
That url must be without language prefix:

```
http://blabla.com/das-video/12/
```

**UPDATED**

If you still want to change default django i18n logic, then you need to subclass

```
django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware
```

then modify some of its methods (`process_request`, `process_response`) and use this modified middleware instead of `LocaleMiddleware`

Comment: you hit the important point, thank you.. sharing was just an example. so opening the ``/de/..`` in english browser WILL show the ``de`` version, no matter what locale, right?

Comment: @doniyor yes, exactly

Comment: but i could write a middleware which removes the language prefix and hands over the request to localemiddleware, right?

Comment: in that case you can raise an endless redirects: you visit `/de/..`, then you being redirected to `/..`, then you being redirected to `/de/..` and so on

Comment: why, i mean, the request gets thru all middlewares only once, right? like. 1. mymiddleware 2. localemiddleware... this flow happens only once per request, right?

Comment: ah, well you mean something like modifying `request.path_info` before localemiddleware. Maybe, but it must be done carefully

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65077/discussion-between-doniyor-and-stalk).